# How to embed Font

Tags: asp.net

I have downloaded a new font file. I want to use this font style in my html page. How do i embed the file in HTML?

Thanks,

Comment: Firstly, are you allowed to - does your licence for the font permit this? The answer will be font-face or sIFR, or just rendering the text to an image and using that, but I don't know all the details.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at @font-face, a CSS declaration that allows you to specify your own fonts.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Font Family Name Here";
    src: url("url/to/font.eot");
}
```

Note that it's still sort of experimental in many browsers, so you'll have to tinker around with it. (Look up Paul Irish's bulletproof method.)

Alternatively, you can use the font in an image and then simply use a font-replacement method. This works if the text is minimal (such as for logos or headers).

Answer (score 1):

do it with [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) if you own rights to use the font on your website ;)